# Mysql Error 1820 must reset password

Tags: mysql

Suddenly getting this error:

`ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.`

I have not changed any config etc? why is it suddenly asking to reset? do passwords expire?

Comment: That would depend on [policies established](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-expiration-policy.html) would be my guess.  Yes passwords can manually be expired, or through policy can be expired automatically.   (See link above)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_new_password');
```

[Reset Mysql Password][1]

**OR**

If you started mysql using **mysql -u root -p** Try

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

[Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-user.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)